# Non-blocking insert into database with node js

Tags: node.js, optimization, blocking

Part of my Node Js app includes reading a file and after some (lightweight, row by row) processing, insert these records into the database.

Original code did just that. The problem is that the file may contain a crazy number of records which are inserted row by row. According to some tests I did, a file of 10000 rows blocks completely the app for some 10 seconds.

My considerations were:

1. Bulk create the whole object at once. This means reading the file, preparing the object by doing for each row some calculation, pushing it to the final object and in the end using Sequelize's bulkcreate. There were two downsides:

   1. A huge insert can be as blocking as thousands of single-row inserts.
   2. This may make it hard to generate reports for rows that were not inserted.
2. Bulk create in smaller, reasonable objects. This means reading the file, iterating each n (ex. 2000) rows by doing the calculations and adding it to an object, then using Sequelize's bulkcreate for the object. Object preparation and the bulkcreate would run asyncroniously. The downside:

   1. Setting the object length seems arbitrary.
   2. Also it seems like an artifice on my side, while there might be existing and proven solutions for this particular situation.
3. Moving this part of the code in another proccess. Ideally limiting cpu usage to reasonable levels for this process (idk. if it can be done or if it is smart).
4. Simply creating a new process for this (and other blocking parts of the code).

This is not the 'help me write some code' type of question. I have already looked around and it seems there is enough documentation. But I would like to invest on an efficient solution, using the proper tools. Other ideas are welcomed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do 1,2,3, or 4. I/O is non blocking in node.js unless you specifically choose to make it blocking with the sync version of the functions you're using. Don't use the sync versions and you don't have to worry about them blocking.

Comment: @Paulpro I am not (explicitly) using any sync version. I am using the async module to manage some processes that should happen synchronously. However, only the last process out of them takes a lot of time, the others are quite short. I am using fs.createReadStream to read the file and fastcsv.fromStream to treat the data stream. But the last process (that of reading the file and writing the content to the db) does take around 1sec/1000 rows and it does block all the api requests I am doing in the meanwhile

Comment: That doesn't seem like anything that should block. The only thing I can think of that would block like that is if you read the entire file into memory (EG. appending all the data received from fastcsv to an array) and then do something like loop over it and do some processing on each row. The actual final write in that case isn't blocking, but the processing in the loop is.

Comment: @Paulpro: Maybe the module I am using (fastcsv) is doing it for me. I haven't been able to confirm this yet. But From what I see, the module reads the file and passes the rows one by one. Here is where I modify and insert the rows one by one as well, without appending anything. I am also using a xml-reading module for a similar feature for xml files and the same thing happens.

Comment: Any chance you can edit your question and show some of the code where you use the data from the fastcsv module and then insert it into the db?

Comment: @Paulpro: I could, but I was doing more research on fasctcsv. Apparently it takes a datastream and keeps node's thread busy until either all the stream is processed, or something pauses the process. I added the line parser.pause(); in the data iteration and the operation was no longer blocking my app. I suspect something similar happens when xml files are imported, but can't do any test right now. When I have more info (for both imports) I will post relevant code or info. Thanks for the tip, I think I was headed in the wrong direction and completely forgot that I/O is non-blocking in itself.